# Python Dictionary - Requests

Tags: python, xml, api, python-requests

I'm trying to get some information from an API that returns XML. I'm looping through the Root, and then the Children however, it's just picking up the first element. Here is some sample xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<result created="2020-06-14T12:54:08-05:00" host="www.systemmonitor.us" status="OK">
<items>
    <site>
        <siteid>144855</siteid>
        <name>
            <![CDATA[NC 99 S]]>
        </name>
        <connection_ok>1</connection_ok>
        <creation_date/>
        <primary_router/>
        <secondary_router/>
    </site>
    <site>
        <siteid>148578</siteid>
        <name>
            <![CDATA[Trial Accounts]]>
        </name>
        <connection_ok>1</connection_ok>
        <creation_date>2013-09-28</creation_date>
        <primary_router/>
        <secondary_router/>
    </site>
    <site>
        <siteid>166088</siteid>
        <name>
            <![CDATA[NEW ACCOUNTS]]>
        </name>
        <connection_ok>1</connection_ok>
        <creation_date>2014-01-08</creation_date>
        <primary_router/>
        <secondary_router/>
    </site>
    <site>
        <siteid>606559</siteid>
        <name>
            <![CDATA[Enhanced]]>
        </name>
        <connection_ok>1</connection_ok>
        <creation_date>2019-09-14</creation_date>
        <primary_router/>
        <secondary_router/>
    </site>
</items>
```

My code consists of this,

```
r = requests.get('https://www.systemmonitor.us//api/? 
apikey=*******c&service=list_sites&clientid=%s' % rmmid)
root = ET.fromstring(r.content)
print(root)
sitelist = {}
for child in root.findall('items'):
    for sites in child.findall('site'):
        print(sites)
        site_info = {}
        name = sites.find("name").text
        guid = sites.find("siteid").text

        sitelist[guid] = site_info
        site_info['id'] = guid
        site_info['name'] = name

        for key, value in sitelist.items():
            print(key, value)

        return redirect('/computers/home')

return redirect('/computers/home')
```

I am getting the first  element, but it seems to not loop through the others. I've tried doing something like using the .iter and different .findall calls. What am I missing on this?

Comment: Pls provide the minimum required code, the dict `sub`...?

Comment: This is everything in the action besides the code coming from stripe which is just going into the var invoices.

Comment: The Subscriptions work fine, and the invoices are even pulling in, they're just not filling up the invoice_list dict.

Comment: All Subs and Invoices are Stripe Queries

Comment: I've updated my question to show all the code. The sample response, and the code asking for it.

Comment: Remove that first return statement "return redirect('/computers/home')" I mean the one inside the nested for loop, it stops executing any code after it not just the nested for loops even anything after the for loops, and that's why you get only the first element, because once the main loop gets the first `"items"` element then the sub loop gets the first `"site"` element do that stuff, and then stops because of that for loop, in other words you are not looping on all of the elements as you are expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a `return` statement in the body of your for-loop would prevent it from looping.  The `return` statement would cause control to leave whatever function this is in.

Comment: Thank you so much, I guess I was overthinking this. As soon as I removed it, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

When your program has `return` in a function (or loop inside the function) it will break out of that function and “returns” the result (value of the expression following the return keyword) to the caller. The statements after the return statements are not executed. If the return statement is without any expression, then the special value None is returned.

The following code will help you understand better.

```
>>> def explain():
    for i in range(10):
        return(i)


>>> explain()
0
>>> def explain_():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
    return "Done"

>>> explain_()
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
'Done'
```